# How to Deploy Django App on Centos server having domain secured With SSL?

Tags: python, django, ssl, centos, django-runserver

I have a Django App which I want to deploy on a `Centos Linux server` having a `global/public IP` which is assigned to a `domain` and is `secured with SSL`.

The System configuration is as:

`centos-release-6-10.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`

`Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)`

When I run the server using:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`,

then it is only accessible from the browser by passing a local IP say

`http://192.xxx.xx.xxx:8000/django_app/home`

But I want to access it from the public/global IP, but it gives an error when I replace the local IP with Global/Public IP or domain assigned to the public IP as:

```
105.168.296.58 took too long to respond.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

When I simply put this public IP in the browser as `https://105.168.296.58` then it redirects the browser to the app/website say `https://mywebsite.com/home` which is running at port 80 on Apache, and shows the assigned domain instead of IP, so IP is working fine.

in settings.py: all hosts are allowed as `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Methods tried are:

1. [by using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30760639/14758388) `django-extensions` as:

`python manage.py runserver_plus --cert certname 0.0.0.0:8000`

2. [by using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68070398/14758388) `django-sslserver` as:

`python manage.py runsslserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

The app runs from both of these methods only locally at `http://192.xxx.xx.xxx:8000/django_app/home`, but None of them worked from a Public IP.

Kindly tell, How to deploy or configure this Django App to Run Outside the Local Network?

Comment: i would use apache as a reverse proxy: https://howto.lintel.in/setup-apache-proxy-django-application/

Comment: I added ```ProxyPreserveHost On```
        ```ProxyPass /static !```
       ```ProxyPass / http://121.136.2.82:8080/```
        ```ProxyPassReverse / http://121.136.2.82:8080/```
        ```ProxyTimeout 300```but it shows ```Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /aws_sm_plots/login.

Reason: Error reading from remote server```

Comment: the proxy is running on the same server as the django application?

then you need to use `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score 0):

i would deploy django like this:

1. install `uwsgi` in your virtualenv

   `pip install uwsgi`
2. create a uwsgi config file (everything inside `<>` has to be edited to your needs

   ```
    # mysite_uwsgi.ini file
    [uwsgi]

    # Django-related settings
    # the base directory (full path)
    chdir           = </path/to/your/project>
    # Django's wsgi file
    module          = <project>.wsgi
    # the virtualenv (full path)
    home            = </path/to/virtualenv>

    # process-related settings
    # master
    master          = true
    # maximum number of worker processes
    processes       = 10
    # the socket (use the full path to be safe
    socket          = </path/to/your/project/mysite.sock>
    # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
    # chmod-socket    = 664
    # clear environment on exit
    vacuum          = true
   ```
3. install nginx and create following config

   ```
    # mysite_nginx.conf

    # the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
    upstream django {
        server unix:///<path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock>; 
    }

    # configuration of the server
    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      80;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name <example.com;> # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        charset     utf-8;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias </path/to/your/mysite/media;>  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        }

        location /static {
            alias </path/to/your/mysite/static>; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     </path/to/your/mysite/uwsgi_params;> # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
   }
   ```
4. Download and copy uwsgi_params to your directory
   https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params
5. symlink config from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

   `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
6. Start uwsgi and nginx

   `uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini`

   `sudo service nginx restart`

don't forget `collectstatic` so that these files can be served.

we added the `mysite_uwsgi.ini` and `uwsgi_params` files to our repository

Comment: However I was using apache, I have configured it using ```django``` + ```mod_wsgi``` + ```apache``` later, which is working on local network, but now running through public network. Thanks for the detailed answer @FabianClemenz, I'll try this approach too.

Comment: Actually, when you hit some public IP, by default it takes some ```web app``` assigned on port ```80```. In the similar way some app which is routed through PHP open as the default page on entering simply this public IP, but gives an error when ```this.public.ip:8080``` is entered in the browser. It runs on the local network but not from the public network via ```Apache webserver```

Comment: maybe you need to open these ports - some firewalls have only `80` or `22` opened. the `listen` section sets the port listened to. I think you don't want everybody to add a port behind the Url?

Comment: I have opened the ports through the firewall so port 8080 is open. Yeah You are right @Fabian, I will not want everybody to add a port behind the Url, but this would come later. Firstly it should run at the public IP

Comment: Do I need to whitelist the port ```8080``` from the ```administrator``` who has provided us with the ```domain or Gloabl/Public IP``` ?

Comment: sure :) just add the ip to `server_name` :)

Comment: i don't know how your network and firewall settings are set up - maybe the admin needs to open it - but its a quick fix to use 80 :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246560/discussion-between-fabianclemenz-and-abhilash-singh-chauhan).

Comment: 80 is already taken by some other app, which can not be shut down, so had thought of deploying it on different port.

Comment: let us discuss in the chat mentioned above