# How to Edit the Django User Verification Email Link

Tags: python, django

My Django User Verification Email Link starts with `http`

Below is an example:

```
http://examplesitexxx.com/accounts/confirm-email/MTA:1poGIh:x7zOj4350ZP6uLhT0wUEp1CRE13jWrvRanofpFgTBkw/
```

I want to change the Verification URL that starts with 'https'.

So I access the file `allauth/templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt`.

In this file I see `{{ activate_url }}`.

It should be a source of Verification Email URL but I can't figure out how to change the `activate_url` that start from `https` from `http`.

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information.

Comment: In production or development? take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610394/how-to-setup-ssl-on-a-local-django-server-to-test-a-facebook-app)

Comment: In development, I meant I want to know how to edit "Django-allauth"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update the ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL setting in your Django project settings file (settings.py).
I done this few weeks ago.

Add the following line to your settings.py file:

```
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"
```

This will change the default HTTP protocol used by the allauth app from "http" to "https". The activate_url variable in the email_confirmation_message.txt template will then use the updated default protocol.

Obviously, ensure that your Django project is running over HTTPS.

Comment: I did it. Thank you very much. 
I appreciate your advice from the bottom of my heart. Sincerely.